# FluentMongo LINQ: How to query a sublist of a class

Tags: c#, linq, list, mongodb, sublist

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class BOa
{

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<BOb> VisiteEffettuate = new List<BOb>();
}

public class BOvalues
{

    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set;}

 }
```

In MongoDB, to be clear, I've got a collection of many BOa. Each of them includes many (a list of...) BOvalues
I wonder how to obtain, with FluentMongo LINQ (or other method), a list of BOvalues with, for example, Score greater than a value or Age between two values.

I wanted to use SelectMany but it seems not supported in fluentmongo.

Which is the best method to obtain this result?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I tried using QueryBuilder instead on LINQ... for example:

```
        var query = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.ElemMatch("VisiteEffettuate", MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.And( 
                MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.GT("Age", 32),
                MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.EQ("Name", "xxxx")
                )
                );

        var res = pazienti.Find(query);
```

...and so on. It seems to work. But QueryBuilder is not so documented and (I'm not sure about that) there's no possibility to create query programmatically (like Dynamic LINQ, for example).

Comment: What's the code that you executed, and what is the error message that you got when you tried it?

Comment: Hi! The classes I reported are examples... I have some tests done with similar classes, but I do not think can be useful: (

Comment: I've made this example: 
var res = from x in documents.AsQueryable() from y in x.VisiteEffettuate where y.Age < 40 select y

Obviously, the program returns "The SelectMany query operator is not supported"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your query using the Any operator.

```
col.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Any(y => y.Age < 40));
```

This will work in FluentMongo right now.  However, FluentMongo is not a supported project any longer due to the official driver gaining linq support.

This does not currently work in the official driver, but is slated for version 1.5.  I'd suggest you stick with the query builders for now until 1.5 comes out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official C# driver which now support LINQ queries natively.  I've used it and it works wonderfully.

Check out the documentation here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial

Comment: Hello! I read that official support for linq driver is not very complete. Anyway I want to try but at this point how best to proceed? You have some reference code (I read the documentation but I don't see examples structured in this way)? At the moment I installed version 1.3.1.4349. I need to update drivers for C# (1.4.2)?

Comment: I removed references to fluentmongo, updated c# mongodb drivers, then I try a linq query like that:

            var res = from x in documents.AsQueryable()
                      from y in x.VisiteEffettuate
                      where y.Age < 40
                      select y;

The results is... the same error that I had with fluentmongo:

"The SelectMany query operator is not supported."